# Adding the first letters of multiple names in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code from another user in this forum (thank you so much).

Now I'm looking to edit it so that I don't have to select a specific column.

So what I want with this code, is that for every name in column C (even second, third, fourth, 5th names), the code needs to grab the first letters and add a dot, and place it inside column B.

For example: S.A.F.G.H. (5 first letters of surnames)

```
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
                S = ""
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            V = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In V
            S = S & Left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
        End If
    Next cell
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, but would your query mean that you want to keep all uppercase letters seperated by dot?

Comment: Ah, no It must be in this order A.B.C. and like A. B. C. (with spaces) because this list is going to be imported in another script which only reads the first letters as A.B.C. (without spaces)

Comment: Still, my question stands. Do you keep uppercase letters only, naturally the first letter of a name. Could you add a sample to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `Selection` to `ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")`:

```
Sub Test()
Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    S = ""
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        V = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In V
            S = S & Left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Let me check this out, brb!

Comment: Is it possible to do this from C2:C?

Because I added C2:C and it crashed with 400 error :O

Because in C1 there is a title which doesn't need to be copied, so if It could get all name from C2 till C and place that in B2:B, that would be perfect.

Comment: You cannot say C2:C. I have added a line that finds the last cell in column C.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this way:

```
Sub testGrabNames()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, cell As Range, V, W, S As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

 For Each cell In rng
    S = ""
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        V = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In V
            S = S & left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
    End If
 Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This gives me a duplicate declaration in the current scope error.

Comment: It's referring to this part, , rng As Range

Comment: @GenjutsuGhost Do you try using the code **as it is**, or had a small 'contribution' of its improvement? `rng` range is declared once... Does your piece of code make part from a larger one? If yes, you must only change `rng` with `rng1` and replace it in the other two places where it appears... `Set rng1 = sh.Range("...` and `For Each cell In rng1`.

Comment: @GenjutsuGhost Did it suddenly start working, or my supposition was correct and you changed `rng` with `rng1`?

Comment: Sorry FaneDuru, I just the code from VBA Pete! But I tested yours also and that also works!

Comment: @GenjutsuGhost OK. But that code used to iterate between more then a milion cells of the column. That's why I posted mine. Only after that he edited the code and used the limitation... Anyhow, no problem with me. Glad you solved your problem.